# How to empty the select element or to select empty option? c# webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium

I need select element to be empty, how can I do that? I tried with selectbytext and empty value, but it did not worked.

```
selectElement2.SelectByText(""); //(failed)

<option value=""></option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Testing1</option>
<option value="2">Testing2</option>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
 new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//selection box"))).selectByIndex(0);

 //or

 new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//selection box"))).selectByValue("");

 //or

 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//selection box")).sendKeys("");
```

Answer (score 1):

This syntax might help

```
$('#DdlSiteName').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Deselect` method from [Select class](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)

```
selectElement2.DeselectByValue("1");
// or
selectElement2.DeselectByIndex(1);
// or
selectElement2.DeselectByText("Testing1");
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you presented, it should just be

```
selectElement2.SelectByValue("");
```

Take a look at [the docs for .Net](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/html/AllMembers_T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_SelectElement.htm)

`SelectByIndex()`, `SelectByText()`, and `SelectByValue()` are available. Index is by the index of the `OPTION` tags, starting with 0, so index = 1 is "Testing1". NOTE: Don't confuse index with value, in this case they are the same. Text is the visible text in the dropdown, e.g. "Testing1" in your sample is currently selected. Value is the `value` inside the `OPTION` tag, e.g. "1" for "Testing1".